# remote debug c++ code in openshift from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, openshift

I would like to remote debug c++ code in openshift from visual studio. I saw that visual studio lets you add ssh credentials to accomplish this. As far as I know it's not possible to remote debug from visual studio using `oc rsh` or `oc exec`.

I created a linux image with my dependencies and an openssh server running on port 8022.

I relaxed the openshift security policies enough to get the ssh server running. I can confirm that ssh is working by opening a terminal within the openshift console and running `ssh -p 8022 admin@localhost bash`.

This is where I'm stuck. I found the IP address of the container within the openshift console, but when I run `ssh -p 8022 admin@10.217.0.5 bash`, ssh fails to connect. When creating the image I told openshift to make port 8022 accessible at port 8022. I thought this would be enough to access it! I have successfully connected to other openshift containers over HTTP using the same mechanism.

Comment: Have you tried adding `-vvv` to the `ssh` command to enable the verbose output? Test that without the `bash` at the end first. Also, the IP address you are trying to use is an internal one. To connect to a remote endpoint you will need the public IP address. Connection to an internal IP address will only work if you are connected to the same network as the other machine in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution my team member found was to use `oc port-forward <pod> 8022:8022`.